# Defining a function without using products

Tags: elementary-set-theory

To set up the fundamental tools of set theory, the usual course is to define first products (using for example Kuratowski's definition), then relations, the functions.

Is it possible to begin this process by defining first functions ? For example first functions then products ($\prod A_i$ seen as a subset of $(\cup A_i)^I$), then relations ?

Or perhaps first relations, then functions, then products ?

Comment: Sure, that's entirely possible. But I'm afraid you'd have to be much more specific to attract satisfactory answers. (Btw. Is it possible that you confused 'products' with 'ordered pairs' in the first line?)

Comment: @StefanMesken: I'd be interested in hearing how you would represent functions inside set theory _without_ involving a concept that is effectively ordered pairs.

Comment: @HenningMakholm What I had in mind would effectively define ordered pairs. I took OP's question to mean whether, let's say in an introductory course to set theory, you could change the order in which you introduce these concepts. And sure, you can do that.

Comment: @StefanMesken: As I said, I would be interested in hearing how. (Unless what you're proposing is to introduce ordered pairs first but keep the _name_ "ordered pair" for them secret until you have defined functions).

Comment: @HenningMakholm A function $f \colon A \to B$ is a subset $f \subseteq \{ \{ \{a,A\}, \{b,B, \{B\} \} \mid a \in A \wedge b \in B \}$ such that for all $a \in A$ there is a unique $b \in B$ such that $\{ \{a,A\}, \{b, B, \{B\} \} \} \in f$. We write $f(a)$ for this unique $b$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Seeing your edit: Now I see what you had in mind. Defining function without any substitute for ordered pairs. Yeah, I don't know how you'd arrange that.

Comment: If you like ordered pairless functions, you will enjoy pointless topology.  Theorem:  every topological space is sober iff it can be expressed as a pointless topological space.  In my opinion, pointless topology is pointless.

Comment: I don't really know how to be more specific about my question. Broadly speaking, I suppose the idea is to find a way to think about functions that does not reduce them to their graph.

Comment: A much broader question but perhaps not totally unrelated would be: how to describe the category $\mathbf{Set}$ (or an equivalent one) without using the set-theoretic model. That is, what is special about the behaviour of its morphisms, what properties do functions between sets have that morphisms of groups, for example, don't.